# Why is this text changing characters in Yosemite?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts

I'm trying to update an app for Yosemite, and one weird problem I'm getting is that the text labels on a custom control are changing characters - not distorting, but changing from "ON" to "KJ" and "OFF" to "KBB". The documents are all encoded as UTF-8 files. If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

The code in question:

```
AKDrawStringAlignedInFrame(@"OFF", [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:0], NSCenterTextAlignment, NSIntegralRect(textRects[0]));
```

which calls:

```
void AKDrawStringAlignedInFrame(NSString *text, NSFont *font, NSTextAlignment alignment, NSRect frame) {
    NSCParameterAssert(font != nil);

    NSBezierPath *textPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithString:text inFont:font];
    NSRect textPathBounds = NSMakeRect(NSMinX([textPath bounds]), [font descender], NSWidth([textPath bounds]), [font ascender] - [font descender]);

    NSAffineTransform *scale = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    CGFloat xScale = NSWidth(frame)/NSWidth(textPathBounds);
    CGFloat yScale = NSHeight(frame)/NSHeight(textPathBounds);
    [scale scaleBy:MIN(xScale, yScale)];
    [textPath transformUsingAffineTransform:scale];

    textPathBounds.origin = [scale transformPoint:textPathBounds.origin];
    textPathBounds.size = [scale transformSize:textPathBounds.size];

    NSAffineTransform *originCorrection = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    NSPoint centeredOrigin = NSRectFromCGRect(AFRectCenteredSize(NSRectToCGRect(frame), NSSizeToCGSize(textPathBounds.size))).origin;
    [originCorrection translateXBy:(centeredOrigin.x - NSMinX(textPathBounds)) yBy:(centeredOrigin.y - NSMinY(textPathBounds))];
    [textPath transformUsingAffineTransform:originCorrection];

    if (alignment != NSJustifiedTextAlignment && alignment != NSCenterTextAlignment) {
        NSAffineTransform *alignmentTransform = [NSAffineTransform transform];

        CGFloat deltaX = 0;
        if (alignment == NSLeftTextAlignment) deltaX = -(NSMinX([textPath bounds]) - NSMinX(frame));
        else if (alignment == NSRightTextAlignment) deltaX = (NSMaxX(frame) - NSMaxX([textPath bounds]));
        [alignmentTransform translateXBy:deltaX yBy:0];

        [textPath transformUsingAffineTransform:alignmentTransform];
    }

    [textPath fill];
}
```

and +[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithString:inFont:] is just

```
+ (NSBezierPath *)bezierPathWithString:(NSString *)text inFont:(NSFont *)font {
    NSBezierPath *textPath = [self bezierPath];
    [textPath appendBezierPathWithString:text inFont:font];
    return textPath;
}
```

Lastly, -[appendBezierPathWithString:text] is:

```
- (void)appendBezierPathWithString:(NSString *)text inFont:(NSFont *)font {
  if ([self isEmpty]) [self moveToPoint:NSZeroPoint];

  NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
  CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString);

  CFArrayRef glyphRuns = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
  CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(glyphRuns);

  for (CFIndex index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    CTRunRef currentRun = (CTRunRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(glyphRuns, index);

    CFIndex glyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(currentRun);

    CGGlyph glyphs[glyphCount];
    CTRunGetGlyphs(currentRun, CTRunGetStringRange(currentRun), glyphs);

    NSGlyph bezierPathGlyphs[glyphCount];
    for (CFIndex glyphIndex = 0; glyphIndex < glyphCount; glyphIndex++)
      bezierPathGlyphs[glyphIndex] = glyphs[glyphIndex];

    [self appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:bezierPathGlyphs count:glyphCount inFont:font];
  }

  CFRelease(line);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got the font installed that you're using?

Comment: I should - I'm using boldSystemFontOfSize, which Yosemite has a new font for - Helvetica Neue. I checked, and Helvetica Neue is installed.

Comment: You need to show the code for `+[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithString:inFont:]`, which is not a standard method. It's presumably introduced by some category on `NSBezierPath` and it's almost certainly at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyph indices are specific to a font. The `appendBezierPathWithString:inFont:` method gets the glyph indices from Core Text (`CTLine` and `CTRun`) but it's not providing the font. Presumably, Core Text is using a default font. Later, it's using those glyph indices but it's passing the desired font, not the font that Core Text used. So, the glyph indices don't mean the same thing.

I think the solution is to construct the attributed string in that method with a font attribute:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font }];
```

(Normally, you have to be careful about using attributes that Core Text will understand, but I believe that `NSFontAttributeName` maps to `kCTFontAttributeName` and `NSFont` is toll-free bridged to `CTFont`.)

Comment: Thanks! That made sense, and your answer worked perfectly. I guess Core Text's default font isn't the default system font anymore.